# Change CSS of Element on Focus Out

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I am having trouble with a bit of jQuery that I am trying to use to style an input. Essentially, I want to be able to check if the input is empty after it goes out of focus and then change the CSS of that input based on this information. Here is my current code:

```
$(".text-input").focusout(function () {
  if ($(".text-input").val()) {
    $(".card").css({
      bottom: "35px",
      "font-size": "0.9em"
    });
  }
});
```

I do not typically use jQuery so forgive the poor syntax. This bit of code is part of a larger project I am working on trying to copy Google's input animations using CSS. Sadly I didn't see a way around using jQuery to make sure that the labels don't cover the input values after they are filled in. Here is a link to the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/hudsontay/pen/NWRdBej?editors=0110) so you can see what I'm talking about. Just type anything in one of the top three inputs then click one something else. You will notice that the label goes back to covering the input space.

Comment: Why you're applying css for card class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of selecting elements using class name inside particular on (click/focus..) methods, try to use with **this** keyword.

```
$(".text-input").focusout(function () {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $(this).siblings('label').css({
            "bottom": "35px",
            "font-size": "0.9em"
        });
    } else {
        $(this).siblings("label").css({
            "bottom": "0",
            "font-size": "1.3em"
        });
    }
});
```

To get the CSS color code variable from script,

```
let styleVar = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);

var blueColor = styleVar.getPropertyValue("--blue"); // 0000FF
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Is there a way I can reverse this behavior if the input goes back to being empty?

Comment: Do you know if using css variables inside jQuery's CSS function for arguments is allowed? Trying to figure out how to include the color style without using the raw hex value

Comment: To get the reverse behavior need to reset the original values in else condition.

Comment: @JamesHamann Updated the snip in above answer

Comment: getComputedStyle, I will need to read up on that.